# Importing 60,000 nodes

Tags: drupal, import, drupal-6

I'm using Table Wizard + Migrate module to import nodes into my Drupal installation.

I need to import around 60,000 questions / answers (they are both nodes) and I thought it would have been an easy task.

However, the migrate process imports 4 nodes per minute, and it would take approximately 11 days to finish the importing.

I was wondering if I can make it faster by importing directly in mysql. But I actually need to create 60,000 nodes. I guess Drupal is going to store additional information in other tables... and it is not that safe.

what do you suggest me to do ? Wait 10 days ?
Thanks

Comment: Can you post the script you currently use, also how do you execute it?

Comment: well, I'm using Migrate module (drupal.org/project/migrate). Together with Table Wizard module I've created the views with the content of external table and then imported it into Drupal nodes (only 2 CCK fields per node, only text). You are actually right, it is very slow.. 4 nodes per minute. Before it was 10 nodes per minute. Your speed 300 nodes in few seconds is amazing for me.

Comment: What is the source of your IMPORT. Is it a csv file on your computer.

Comment: no it is mysql table already imported into the drupal database. The Table Wizard module create views of this table and prepare the rows to be imported. I can offer you more details. I need to boost this bloody import.

Comment: Have you tried this on a different server or computer ? Because last time I used this tool, the import was pretty fast.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Table migrate should be orders of magnitude faster than that.

Are you using pathauto?

If yes, try disabling the pathauto module, often causes big performance problems on import.

Second, if disabling pathauto doesn't work, turn off all non-essential modules you may have running - some modules do crazy stuff. Eliminate other modules as the sources of the problem.

Third, is MySQL db log turned on? That can have a big performance impact - not the level you are talking about, but its something to consider.

Third, install xdebug, and tail your mysql log to see exactly whats happening.

What is your PHP memory limit?

Do you have plenty of disk space left?

Comment: YOU ROCK. The issue was pathauto indeed. Now it runs fast: 1967 nodes / minute. I will enable path auto after importing it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It is same impact for user import?

Answer (score 1):

If you're not doing it, you should use drush to migrate the nodes in batches. You could even write a shell script for it, if you want it automated. Using the command line should lower the time it takes to import the nodes a lot. With a script, you can make it an automated task that you don't have to worry about.

One thing I want to note though, 4 nodes per minute is very low. I once needed to import some nodes from a CSV file, using migrate etc. I needed to import 300 nodes, with location, 4-5 CCK fields and I did it in a matter of seconds. So if you only import 4 nodes per minute, you either have extremely complex nodes, or something fishy is going on.

What are the specs of the computer you are using for this? Where's the import source located?

Comment: 1) I'm using Migrate module php script, if I can run its script from Drush (I have no idea how), I can do it with Drush from terminal. 2) I'm using Macbook Dual Core (32 bit), 2GB ram.  3) The import source are 2 tables inside the same Drupal database.

Answer (score 1):

This is a tough topic, but within Drupal actually very well covered. I don't know the ins- and outs. But do know where to look.

- [Data Mining Drupalgroup](http://groups.drupal.org/data-mining) has some pointers, knowledge and information on processing large amounts of data in PHP/Drupal.
- Drupal core has batch-functionality [built in](http://api.drupal.org/api/group/batch) and called [BatchAPI](http://drupal.org/node/180528) At your service when writing modules! For a working example, see [this tutorial on CSV import](http://www.thedrupalblog.com/creating-batch-api-operation-parse-large-csv-file).

Answer (score 0):

4 node per minute is incredibly slow. Migrate shouldn't normally take that long. You could speed things up a bit by using Drush, but probably not enough to get a reasonable import time (hours, not days). That wouldn't really address your core problem: your import itself is taking too long. The overhead of the Migrate GUI isn't that big.

Importing directly into MySQL would certainly be faster, but there's a reason Migrate exists. Node database storage in Drupal is complicated, so it's generally best to let Drupal work it out rather than trying to figure out what goes where.

Are you using Migrate's hooks to do additional processing on each node? I'd suggest adding some logging to see what exactly is taking so long. Test it on 10 nodes at a time until you figure out the lag before doing the whole 60k.

Comment: Yeah it is slow: Imported 2 in 28.7 sec (4/min) - continuing with 'import answers'. I'm not doing additional processing. Just importing the rows of a table to nodes of a specific content type (and assigning 3 CCK fields). How can I add some logging ?

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem on a Drupal 7 install. Left it run all week-end on an import, and it only imported 1,000 lines of a file.

The funny thing is that *exactly* the same import on a pre-production machine was taking 90 minutes.

We ended up comparing the source code (making sure we are at the same commit in git), the database schema (identical), the quantity of node on each machine (not identical but similar)...

Long story made short, the only significant difference between the two machines was the `max_execution_time` option in the `php.ini` settings file.

The production machine had `max_execution_time = 30`, while the pre-production machine had `max_execution_time = 3000`. It looks like the migrate module has a kind of system to handle "short" `max_execution_time` that is less than optimal.

**Conclusion** : set `max_execution_time = 3000` or more in your `php.ini`, that helps a lot the migrate module.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add a note saying the pathauto disable really does help.  I had an import of over 22k rows and before disabling it took over 12 hours and would crash multiple times during the import.  After disabling pathauto and then running the import, it took only 62 minutes and didn't crash once.

Just a heads up, I created a module that before the import starts, disables the pathauto module, and then upon the feed finishing, reenables the pathauto module.  Here's the code from the module in case anyone needs to have this ability:

```
function YOURMODULENAME_feeds_before_import(FeedsSource $source) {
  $modules = array('pathauto');
  drupal_set_message(t('The ').$modules[0].t(' has been deployed and should begin to disable'), 'warning');
  module_disable($modules);
  drupal_set_message(t('The ').$modules[0].t(' module should have been disabled'), 'warning');
}

function YOURMODULENAME_feeds_after_import(FeedsSource $source) {
  $modules = array('pathauto');
  module_enable($modules);
  drupal_set_message($modules[0].t(' should be reenabled now'), 'warning');
}
```